# ASP.net Identity Custom Tables using OwinContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm trying to implement custom tables to store users/roles etc. in a SQL server DB using Entity framework 6.

I've create a base DbContext that derives from IdentityDbContext

```
 public class MainContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
 {
    public MainContext()
        : base("name=Main")
    {
    }

    public static MainContext Create()
    {
        return new MainContext();
    }
  }
```

I also have a custom user class that inherits IdentityUser

```
public class ServiceUser : IdentityUser{

}
```

In the ConfigureAuth the defualt code was:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {                
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

 ..
}
```

I want to be able to use my MainContext here instead of the ApplicationDBContext, when I try the following

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(MainContext.Create());
```

I get an error

> 'The type arguments for method
>   'Owin.AppBuilderExtensions.CreatePerOwinContext(Owin.IAppBuilder,
>   System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the
>   type arguments
>   explicitly.
>   '

Considering the default ApplicationDbContext looks like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("Main", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

I cannot see what is different that would cause this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foolish mistake, it should have been

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(MainContext.Create);
```

and not

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(MainContext.Create());
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<IdentityDbContext>(MainContext.Create);
```