# Send connection string to ApplicationDBContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I have customized the ApplicationDBContext class to receive a connection string via its constructor. It can connect to the database OK when called directly however when called through the app.CreatePerOwnContext I am unable to call it. My class definition is below:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(string databaseConnection)
        : base(databaseConnection, throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create(string databaseConnection)
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext(databaseConnection);
    }
}
```

The problem is when it is called by Startup.Auth.cs in the following line.

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
```

The create method also takes a connection string but the following does not work

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create(connectionString));
```

It produces the following error:

```
Error   1   The type arguments for method 'Owin.AppBuilderExtensions.CreatePerOwinContext<T>(Owin.IAppBuilder, System.Func<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

What is the correct syntax to send a connection string to the ApplicationDbContext class so that the Owin context can reference it?

The connection string is correct but for completeness the code which sets it is below.

```
string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: hard to answer when you don't show how you are assigning the value of the connectionstring.. you need to show all relevant code.. also use the debugger..

Comment: The connection string is correct. I can connect to the database fine using the class constructor. Where I falldown is calling the method through app.CreatePerOwnContext.

Comment: the error is telling you exactly what the issue is.. why don't you do a simple google search on the following `ApplicationDbContext.Create` and look for examples.. also if you're going to paste code.. please show all relevant code.. we are not mind readers..also do a separate google search on MSDN `createperowincontext`

Comment: @ThreeValueLogic Have you tried doing what the error says and specify the type arguments explicity? Like Milen Pavlov's answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781885/asp-net-identity-custom-tables-using-owincontext).

Comment: "why don't you do a simple google search on the following ApplicationDbContext.Create and look for examples."

I did. I was unable to find a single one which passed an argument to create.

Comment: Unfortunately Milens answer is incorrect. I did stumble upon it earlier but the solution was to not pass an argument to create.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please have a look at the [declaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497591(v=vs.108).aspx) of the method you are using:

```
public static IAppBuilder CreatePerOwinContext<T>(
    this IAppBuilder app,
    Func<T> createCallback) where T : class, IDisposable
```

It is expecting an argument of the type `Func<T>`.

So you need to change your code to:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => ApplicationDbContext.Create(connectionString));
```